# FreePBX connected to SIP trunk, can't connect SIP phone

Tags: centos, asterisk

I've set up a FreePBX server that has a direct connection to the internet (no router/NAT). I've been able to connect it to a SIP trunk, and have created an extension for use with an IP phone. Thing is I can't get the IP phone (or any softphone software) to connect to the PBX.

Logging into Asterisk and doing a 'sip show peers' produces:

```
Name/username             Host                                    Dyn Forcerport Comedia    ACL Port         Status      Description
200                       (Unspecified)                            D  No         No          A  0        UNKNOWN
DIDLogic/XXXXX            178.63.143.236                              Auto (No)  No             5060     OK (107 ms)
2 sip peers [Monitored: 1 online, 1 offline Unmonitored: 0 online, 0 offline]
```

I've set SIP debugging to on and see the communication between the server and SIP trunk, but when I attempt to register a device for extension 200 I see nothing. I was seeing messages for a brief time that reported that the password was incorrect. Strange thing was it was after a long stretch of seeing nothing, and I'm not sure what, if anything, I did for it to get through.

```
<--- SIP read from UDP:178.63.143.236:5060 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5061;branch=z9hG4bK0e613a6d;rport=5061
From: <sip:XXXXX@sip.didlogic.net>;tag=as64d70f66
To: <sip:XXXXX@sip.didlogic.net>;tag=b27e1a1d33761e85846fc98f5f3a7e58.4b9a
Call-ID: 220d02ce752c0115395b99742e37d13a@[::1]
CSeq: 112 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:XXXXXXXXXXX@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5061>;expires=120
Server: kamailio (4.0.3 (x86_64/linux))
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (9 headers 0 lines) ---
[2014-09-20 13:28:24] NOTICE[18929]: chan_sip.c:23980 handle_response_register: Outbound     Registration: Expiry for sip.didlogic.net is 120 sec (Scheduling reregistration in 105 s)
Really destroying SIP dialog '220d02ce752c0115395b99742e37d13a@[::1]' Method: REGISTER
```

I've tried disabling iptables on the server, and I've put my IP phone in my routers DMZ but still no luck.

The sip_additional.conf file looks like:

```
[200]
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
context=from-internal
host=dynamic
trustrpid=yes
sendrpid=no
type=friend
nat=no
port=5060
qualify=yes
qualifyfreq=60
transport=Auto
avpf=no
force_avp=no
icesupport=no
encryption=no
callgroup=
pickupgroup=
dial=SIP/200
mailbox=200@device
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
callerid=Personal <200>
callcounter=yes
faxdetect=no
cc_monitor_policy=generic

[DIDLogic]
disallow=all
host=sip.didlogic.net
user=XXXXX
defaultuser=XXXXX
fromuser=XXXXX
authname=XXXXX
secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
insecure=port,invite
type=friend
qualify=yes
allow=ulaw
context=from-trunk-sip-DIDLogic
```

Comment: You trace is not full and show nothing. you have configure NAT acordinly to your network setup.

Comment: Granted the trace isn't full, but it's nothing but messages relating to the trunk connection. When I attempt a connection from a device (ip phone or softphone) nothing shows up in the trace about it at all. The server isn't behind any kind of NAT, although my phones are. What kind of configuration would be necessary for that?

Comment: Need full config if you want someone help you. If your asterisk is NOT behind NAT, then have be no VIA in reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was just that asterisk was listening on 5061, not 5060. I find that strange, as I didn't change any default port settings anywhere in FreePBX.